# Team Foundation Service + Git on-premise build controller

Tags: git, tfs, tfsbuild

I currently have a Team Foundation Service Git repository.

When trying to utilize a TFS2012 on-premise build controller, I get the follow error:

```
TF215097: An error occurred while initializing a build for build definition CI Check-In: 
Exception Message: Cannot create unknown type '{clr-namespace:Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Activities.Core;assembly=Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Activities}SetBuildNumber'. (type XamlObjectWriterException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter.WriteStartObject(XamlType xamlType)
   at System.Xaml.XamlServices.Transform(XamlReader xamlReader, XamlWriter xamlWriter, Boolean closeWriter)
   at System.Activities.XamlIntegration.FuncFactory`1.Evaluate()
   at System.Activities.DynamicActivity.OnInternalCacheMetadata(Boolean createEmptyBindings)
   at System.Activities.Activity.InternalCacheMetadata(Boolean createEmptyBindings, IList`1& validationErrors)
   at System.Activities.ActivityUtilities.ProcessActivity(ChildActivity childActivity, ChildActivity& nextActivity, Stack`1& activitiesRemaining, ActivityCallStack parentChain, IList`1& validationErrors, ProcessActivityTreeOptions options, ProcessActivityCallback callback)
   at System.Activities.ActivityUtilities.ProcessActivityTreeCore(ChildActivity currentActivity, ActivityCallStack parentChain, ProcessActivityTreeOptions options, ProcessActivityCallback callback, IList`1& validationErrors)
   at System.Activities.ActivityUtilities.CacheRootMetadata(Activity activity, LocationReferenceEnvironment hostEnvironment, ProcessActivityTreeOptions options, ProcessActivityCallback callback, IList`1& validationErrors)
   at System.Activities.Validation.ActivityValidationServices.InternalActivityValidationServices.InternalValidate()
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.WorkflowHelpers.ValidateWorkflow(Activity activity, ValidationSettings validationSettings)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Hosting.BuildProcessCache.LoadFromXaml(String workflowXaml, TextExpressionImports textExpressionImports)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Hosting.BuildControllerWorkflowManager.PrepareRequestForBuild(IBuildDetail build, WorkflowRequest request, IDictionary`2 dataContext)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Hosting.BuildWorkflowManager.TryStartWorkflow(WorkflowRequest request, WorkflowManagerActivity activity, BuildWorkflowInstance& workflowInstance, Exception& error, Boolean& syncLockTaken)
```

When using a Hosted Controller, everything works as it should. It appears that my on-premise build controller is unable to resolve Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Activties.Core.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you on Update 1 of TFS 2012? If so, are the build services on the server that hoses the build controller on Update 1 as well?

Comment: @JamesTupper Yes. THe on-premise build server is on TFS 2012 Express Update 2 (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36539). I'm using a clean install of VS2012 with Updates 1, 2, and Git tools. This may sounds stupid, but can you clarify what you mean by "build tools"? I've gone as far as installing VS2012 with updates 1, 2, and Git tools as well because my first instinct was that TFS 2012 Express Build Services didn't install necessary assemblies. FYI, the solution I'm attempting to build does not require any customer assemblies.

Comment: After installing TFS onto a machine, you can then configure what you want the machine to do. For instance, if you run a multi-tier install of TFS, you would install TFS on your app-tier, and then use the _Advanced Configuration Wizard_ to install your app tier. Configuring _Build Services_ after installing TFS is what I'm talking about. I'm just double checking to ensure that your TFS versions are consistent.

Comment: Any resolution to this? I am in the same boat. I have TFS 11.0.60204.1 installed (Dev11.Update2.CTP3) on my build server. Team projects build fine, but Git ones fail.

Comment: Not yet. I did a re-install of everything and it's not working. I looked into \Microsoft Team Foundation Server 11.0\Tools\ and I have do not have Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Activities.dll which might be the issue.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved?  I am have the exact same problem. (1) TFS Service using Git repo, (2) Windows Server 2012 on premis server, (3) Team Foundation Server 2012 - Build Server only configured, (4) VS 2012 Ultimate, (5) VS 2012 Update 2 RTM installed (after VS2012 and TFS Build Server installed).

Answer (score 3):

The version of the build controller that ships in Update 2 does not know how to talk to Git repositories yet I'm afraid. This is because the support for Git based team projects in Team Build is still being developed.  There is support for it in the version of the build controller that is installed in the Hosted Build Controller so you have to use the hosted build servers at the moment to do Git builds against tfs.visualstudio.com.

The plan is for the build controller to support Git when Git support is also provided in the box for Visual Studio and Team Foundation Server - i.e. the next major release of VS/TFS.